# Empty SVG file errror while it's not

Tags: python, svg, pycairo

Working with Pycairo, I create an "SVGSurface" (which create for me an svg file) and I write on it using a "context". Now after I finish, I need to use the svg file, but it seems that the file is not closed so that it gave me an error telling that the document is empty.

```
    ps = cairo.SVGSurface("header.svg", width, height)
    cr = cairo.Context(ps)
    drawRectangle (cr,
        papersize.convert_length(int(lg[0]), "px","pt"),
        papersize.convert_length(int(lg[2]), "px","pt"),
        papersize.convert_length(int(lg[1])-int(lg[0])-1, "px","pt"),
        papersize.convert_length(int(lg[3])-int(lg[2])-1, "px","pt"),
        0, 0, 0.5
    )
    cr.show_page()
    head = st.fromfile("header.svg")
```

It gives me this error :

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/svgutils/transform.py", line 249, in fromfile
    svg_file = etree.parse(fid)
  File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 3427, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:81117)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1832, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:118116)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1852, in lxml.etree._parseFilelikeDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:118399)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1747, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFilelike (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:117187)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1162, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFilelike (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:111914)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 595, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:105109)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 706, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:106817)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 635, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:105671)
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Document is empty, line 1, column 1 (line 1)
```

I tried to close the file with os but it didn't work

Comment: Missing `ps.finish()`

Comment: @DietrichEpp It works, thank you !